# Ranking by Date and Resetting on Column Changes in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

How can I rank a dataset based on orderly date while resetting the ranking to 1 whenever there is a change in `id`, `supplier`, `item id`, `cogs`, or type columns?

Additionally, if there is no change in these columns but the date is different, the ranking should continue from where it left off. I have tried using `lag() function over (partition by id, supplier, item id, cogs, type order by date)` but it doesn't give me the desired results since it doesn't reset the ranking when there is a change in the other columns.

The purpose of this ranking is to be able to identify each data date and the next date change. For the last data if there's no input yet the next date change is the current timestamp.

[image]

Comment: `date`s in 2nd and 3rd rows are same, therfore 2nd and 3rd rows are interchangable by  `order by date` . It will affterct the `expected rank` and the result is not determistic.  kindly correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger the date, id, and supplier are the same, but the item ID is different, which causes the rank to start from 1 again. Thank you

Comment: I've add some more explanation of what I try to say. kindly check if it make sense to you.

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger 
Thank you so much for helping me. I was trying your query yesterday and try to work around with gaps and island approach. 

I think this one works but still has some limitations due to many suppliers and transasctions. 
-> row_number() over (partition by id order by date asc, id) - row_number() over (partition by id , supplier, item_id, cogs order by date asc, id) as grp <- 

afterwards:

row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by date asc, id) as expected_rank

I'm still working on it and hope's to fix it soon. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dates in 2nd and 3rd rows are same, therfore 2nd and 3rd rows are interchangable by order by date . It will affterct the expected rank and the result become non-determistic.

If you sort your table by `date`, sometimes **result set #1** is returned and sometimes **result set #2** returned since 2nd and 3rd row has same `date` time. And I think this will affect the rank of each row. (see below)

■ results set #1

| id | date | supplier | item_id | cogs | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1036 | 2023-01-02 08:53:49.000 | star | 10 | 400 | 1 |
| 1036 | `2023-01-02 16:23:50.000` | moose | `10` | 400 | 1 |
| 1036 | `2023-01-02 16:23:50.000` | moose | `06` | 400 | `1` |
| 1036 | 2023-01-02 16:35:50.000 | moose | 10 | 400 | `1` |
| 1036 | 2023-01-02 16:35:50.000 | moose | 06 | 400 | 1 |

■ results set #2

| id | date | supplier | item_id | cogs | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1036 | 2023-01-02 08:53:49.000 | star | 10 | 400 | 1 |
| 1036 | `2023-01-02 16:23:50.000` | moose | `06` | 400 | 1 |
| 1036 | `2023-01-02 16:23:50.000` | moose | `10` | 400 | `1` |
| 1036 | 2023-01-02 16:35:50.000 | moose | 10 | 400 | `2` |
| 1036 | 2023-01-02 16:35:50.000 | moose | 06 | 400 | 1 |

---

Assuming that your datatset has a distinct date, you can consider below *gaps and islands* approch.  (I've slightly changed `date` so as not to be duplicate.)

```sql
with sample_table (id, date, supplier, item_id, cogs) as ( values
  (1036, '2023-01-02 08:53:49.000', 'star', 10, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 16:23:50.000', 'moose', 10, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 16:23:51.000', 'moose', 06, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 16:35:50.000', 'moose', 10, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 16:35:51.000', 'moose', 06, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 17:03:38.000', 'moose', 06, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 17:03:39.000', 'moose', 10, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 17:18:36.000', 'star', 10, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 17:20:33.000', 'star', 10, 360),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 17:25:33.000', 'star', 10, 360),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 18:13:45.000', 'moose', 10, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-02 18:13:49.000', 'moose', 06, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-03 06:18:19.000', 'star', 10, 400),
  (1036, '2023-01-03 07:49:56.000', 'star', 10, 400)
)

select id, date, supplier, item_id, cogs,
       -- rank over each islands
       rank() over (partition by grp order by date) as expected_rank 
  from (
    -- find *islands*
    select *, count_if(is_changed) over (order by date) as grp 
      from (
        select *,
               -- find *gaps*
               lag(id) over (order by date) <> id or
               lag(supplier) over (order by date) <> supplier or
               lag(item_id) over (order by date) <> item_id or
               lag(cogs) over (order by date) <> cogs as is_changed
          from sample_table
      )
  )
order by date;
```

**Query results**

[image]